# Push splitted text with comma to next line in table td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to prevent text with comma from splitting to next line. Here's an example:

[image]

but instead, I want the text to move to next line if it's splitting. Here's the result I want:

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th width="50%;">Address</th>
    <th width="50%;">Email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="">416, Willow Brook Lane, Suite 567, Apartment Riverview, Brookside Complex, Greenfield Eastern District, Riverside County, California, United States</td>
    <td>name@email.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get the output? Thank you.

Comment: You cannot do this with CSS alone. You need to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to turn off automatic wrapping with `white-space: nowrap;` and then control the wrapping yourself using [line-break opportunity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) `<wbr>` elements. You can use a script to replace every comma with a comma followed by a `<wbr>`.

Note that when you run this snippet you will need to use the **full page** link and then adjust the browser width to see the differences in wrapping behaviour between the two cells.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.break-at-commas').forEach(e => {
  e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replaceAll(',',',<wbr>')
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
}
.break-at-commas {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Break At Commas</th>
    <th>Default</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="break-at-commas">416, Willow Brook Lane, Suite 567, Apartment Riverview, Brookside Complex, Greenfield Eastern District, Riverside County, California, United States</td>
    <td>416, Willow Brook Lane, Suite 567, Apartment Riverview, Brookside Complex, Greenfield Eastern District, Riverside County, California, United States</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just posted mine, but yours is cool. Nice work.

Comment: That's not what he wants. He wants a hard line break *after* each comma. Although the JS script can be modified to do that.

Comment: @fatpenguin, no, his picture of what he wants clearly shows that he wants line breaks to occur at commas, but not every comma -- only when necessary. That’s why I’ve used `<wbr>` instead of `<br>`.

Comment: You are correct, not *every* comma. However he wants to retain the commas, not replacing them.

Comment: My JS code replaces each comma with a comma plus a `<wbr>`. It works.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to manipulate the contents of your `td` with JavaScript to make each segment into an element that has a `display` property of `inline-block`. I made a pen that I think does close to what you're looking for. https://codepen.io/motionharvest/pen/bGOjZPx

The code splits the text by comma, then wraps each segment into a span, and gives it the style of `display: inline-block`. I'm not seeing an extra space after the comma, but hopefully this helps.

```js
let splitElem = document.getElementById("split");
let splitElemText = splitElem.innerText;
let splittedText = splitElemText.split(",");
splitElem.innerText = "";

splittedText.forEach((segment, index) => {
    let segmentElement = document.createElement("span");
    segmentElement.innerText = segment;
    if(index < splittedText.length - 1) {
        segmentElement.innerText += ", "
    }
    segmentElement.style.display = "inline-block";
    splitElem.append(segmentElement);
})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th width="50%;">Address</th>
    <th width="50%;">Email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="" id="split">416, Willow Brook Lane, Suite 567, Apartment Riverview, Brookside Complex, Greenfield Eastern District, Riverside County, California, United States</td>
    <td>name@email.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```